# Return result only if all conditions meet

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck with my thoughts and cannot figure out a solution.

I have a table of items with many fields. But the critical for this discussion are ID, STATUS, CATEGORY.

I would like to query this table and return a result **only** if ALL conditions meet. I do not care how many records are returned, I am just checking if I am getting record(s) results or empty results.

****The logic:**** If ALL Service items are completed and there are Upgrade items that are not completed.

For example the table below

```
ITEM ID  STATUS     CATEGORY
10       COMPLETED  SERVICE
20       OPEN       SERVICE
30       COMPLETED  UPGRADE
```

With the case above^ I would like to return 0 records as not all conditions meet.

Another Example

```
ITEM ID  STATUS     CATEGORY
10       COMPLETED  SERVICE
20       OPEN       SERVICE
30       COMPLETED  UPGRADE
40       OPEN       UPGRADE
```

With the case above^ I would like to return 0 records as not all conditions meet.

Any idea how I can achieve this? SQL Server 2016/2019

Cheers!

Comment: what do you mean by all conditions ? can you please include a row, where all conditions are met ?

Comment: For example, the below recordset should return a result.
All 'Service' Items are completed and there are 'Upgrade' items that are not completed.

```
ITEM ID  STATUS     CATEGORY
10       COMPLETED  SERVICE
20       COMPLETED  SERVICE
30       COMPLETED  UPGRADE
40       OPEN       UPGRADE
```

Comment: Please edit and update the last comment into your question.

Comment: @Squirrel, sorry. tried to format it a few times... not get better.
Another Try fr better formatting - 

For example, the below recordset should return a result. All 'Service' Items are completed and there are 'Upgrade' items that are not completed. 

| ITEM ID | STATUS    | CATEGORY |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 10        | COMPLETED | SERVICE|
| 20         | OPEN         | SERVICE  |
| 30      | COMPLETED | UPGRADE  |
| 40      | COMPLETED | UPGRADE  |

Comment: For your last example, `ITEM ID 20` is `OPEN` and all `SERVICE` are `COMPLETED`, it does not stratified your condition. Why it should return a result ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70647417/edit) your question to include the additional examples. Not in the comments please. It is hard to read in comments

Answer (score 2):

Sounds what you wanted can be achieve using 2 `EXISTS` conditions

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  NOT EXISTS  -- ALL Service items are completed 
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   tbl 
           WHERE  Category = 'SERVICE'
           AND    Status   <> 'COMPLETED'
       )
AND    EXISTS      -- there are Upgrade items that are not completed
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   tbl 
           WHERE  Category = 'UPGRADE'
           AND    Status   <> 'COMPLETED'
       )
```

Comment: Cool!
Completely forgot about 'EXISTS'.

Comment: Any reason that I get also records with category null?
Cheers

Comment: please provide sample data for the above mention scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can go for simple query, as given below:

```sql
SELECT [Item ID], [Status],[Category]
FROM TableName
WHERE Status = 'COMPLETED' AND Category = 'SERVICE'
```

Comment: This does not cover all cases. e.g. when I have status <> Completed. I would like that 0 records returned.